# How to write an onChange event through hooks?

Tags: reactjs, switch-statement, react-hooks, onchange, i18next

I would like to register the event onChange through Hooks

```
const { i18n } = useTranslation();
const [locale, setLocale] = useState('en')
const handleChange = (lang) => {
    setLocale(lang)
    i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
}
```

tried using the **select** but ended up choosing **Switch**

```
``return (
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <div className={styles.switchBorder}>
           <Switch className={styles.switch} checkedChildren="EN" unCheckedChildren="RU"
                checked={locale} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.checked)}
            />
        </div>
    </div>
)``
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleChange = ({currentTarget}) => {
const {checked: lang} = currentTarget;
setLocale(lang)
i18n.changeLanguage(lang);}
```

`onChange={handleChange}`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Something doesn't work, an error falls "TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'checked' of 'currentTarget' as it is undefined."

Comment: maybe try `thisconst handleChange = ({target}) => { const {value: lang} = target;` and put `value` prop instead `checked` in the component `<Switch className={styles.switch} checkedChildren="EN" unCheckedChildren="RU"
                value={locale} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.checked)}`

Answer (score 0):

```
  const handleChange = () => {
    if (locale === 'en') {
        setLocale('ru');
        i18n.changeLanguage( 'ru');
    } else {
        setLocale('en');
        i18n.changeLanguage( 'en');
    }
};
```